# Oracle/LDAP: How to specify middleware home during installing WebLogic server?

Tags: oracle, ldap, weblogic12c

I'm following the instructions to set up an Oracle LDAP server with internal services(WebLogic Server and OID).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/ods11g-use-cases-084303.html#Option1

```
(Step 1 : install WebLogic Server. 
Step 2 : install Identity Management )
```

Seems the documentations are not up-to-date, since I didn't see the step of "creating new middleware home" during installing WebLogic Server, but Identity Management installation requires a valid middleware home. I specify the oracle home of WebLogic server, but it says invalid.

Screen-shot on error

[image]

Highly appreciate for any suggestion or instruction.

Comment: Looks you need provide a valid folder to install weblogic. you should know WeblogicInstallation Directories Structure before that. #please choose a valid folder by click browse.

Comment: FYI:http://weblogic-tips.com/2012/08/26/weblogic-12c-installation-directories/

Comment: @TankSui , thanks for your response. Actually, my problem is not the weblogic not installed, but identity management. I created a new directory named "orahome" for weblogic and it is successfully installed. The latest version 12.2.1.2 of weblogic doesn't require a middleware home, but Oracle Home. (In my case, I use $ORACLE_DIR\orahome). Well, Oracle documentation says the identity management should be installed under the same middleware home as weblogic, I speicified "$ORACLE_DIR\orahome", but it complains it's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the versions of your installations are no more compatible, try using a lower version of weblogic like 10.3.6.